# Незапоминающие скобки в js

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

```
var str = "<a>{{link}}<span>{{span}}</span>";
var res = str.match(/(?:\{\{)[^(\{\{)(\}\})]*(?:\}\})/g);
```

Здравствуйте. Из строки str надо "достать", в данном случае, link и span (без фигурных скобок). [Тут](http://javascript.ru/RegExp) вычитал, что конструкция (?:x):

> (?:x) Находит x, но не запоминает найденное. Это называется "незапоминающие скобки". Найденная подстрока не сохраняется в массиве результатов и свойствах RegExp.Как и все скобки, объединяют находящееся в них в единый подпаттерн.

Собственно вопрос - почему моя регулярка захватывает эти скобки (вывод через консоль.лог: `["{{link}}", "{{span}}"]` )?

P.S. если использовать (?=}}) вместо вторых "незапоминающих скобок", то закрывающие фигурные скобки не попадают в результат (вывод через консоль.лог: `["{{link", "{{span"]` ). Но как тогда быть с поиском назад?

<h1>Проблема решена</h1>

```
var str = "<a>{{link}}<span>{{span}}</span>";
var res = str.match(/[^(\{\{)(\}\})]+(?=\}\})/g);//ищем все, кроме (}}) и ({{) перед (}})
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте про разницу между [str.match(/.../g)](http://javascript.ru/String/match) и [regexp.exec(str)](http://javascript.ru/RegExp/exec)

Comment: str.match:
> Если же для регулярного выражения указан флаг "g", то метод возвращает массив, содержащий все совпадения.

Флаг g указал и хочу массив.

Comment: Вот он вам и вернул массив «всех» совпадений, а именно, всё что подходит по паттерн, т.е. вместе с фигурными скобками, используйте exec.

Comment: Хм. Я попробовал exec с этим же шаблоном:

    var str = "<a>{{link}}<span>{{span}}</span>";
    var res = /(?:\{\{)[^(\{\{)(\}\})]*(?=\}\})/g.exec(str)
    console.dir(res);

Но в res все равно `"{{link"`. Может я вашу идею как-то недопонял?